# DRAM -> However all I want is the capacitor array, (or does a circuit like this even exist)?

Tags: capacitor, transistor-array

Sorry, this is a very odd question, I've however exhausted my google-fu and I don't even know what question to ask to get the information that I'm looking for. (I'm a programmer so pardon the lack of electronics lingo, as this isn't my specialization).

I'm looking for a component that has the same setup as a dram chip (specifically the capacitor array and if possible the row/column decoder for addressing). I need to store a series of analog low voltage values for a very brief period of time (and signal loss as the capacitor 'bleeds' is acceptable).

Does a circuit like this exist? If so what's it called?

Ps. I'm asking from a programmer perspective, however I need something like this for a project I'm working on. Any help with a starting block would be huge, even a name of a component that has that setup.

Comment: This is an odd question indeed and it is highly likely that the thing you are thinking of will not work. Better describe your intended application and why a digital storage is not good enough for you..

Comment: "very brief" and "low voltage" will mean completely different things to different people. Be more specific and give an idea of how many values you want to store.

Comment: It will work and such ICs used to exist, but shopping questions are off-topic. IC questions _should_ be on-topic but they are currently not.

Comment: @pipe A general name would be on topic, I guess. It's like "what is the name of a component which will output logical `1` iff all of it's inputs are `1`".

Comment: is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket-brigade_device) what you're after?

Comment: Digital storage isn't 'good' in this case because simply what I'm building is an analog computer more or less. (Keep in mind this is early research so I'm still putting together the entire idea). I've already used adding op-amps for most of the 'math' and the signal value in the design are not meant to be accurate completely. (basically the circuit more of less is just read, add values, put them back into an array).  

By drawing them out of a capacitor I can pull/read/write back to the same address. Also it doesn't need to be 100% accruate with true values.

Comment: @Neil_UK very close, and that component will help. Thanks for sharing that. But I need basically the equivalent of analog digital storage if that makes sense.

Comment: Yet your address *is* digital, not analog... And your *not 100% accurate* implies that you are going to have some thresholding, i.e. quantization.

Comment: (Address is not an issue in this case, I've got a solution for that already (programmer). However I wouldn't even of known about the threshold issue, thanks again).

Comment: It sounds like what you need is a writeable charge coupled device.   You can also look at magnetic core memory.

Comment: @Metric Note that some of the early _digital_ computers used a [sequential memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_line_memory), which you could only read out after some time when the data had been cycled through.

Comment: @ pipe (that's exactly how I'm handling it :D actually in this case). 

@ Adam thanks, however they have CCDs that can STORE voltage values?

Comment: Modify a casette recorder as the stack memory :-)

Comment: Hahaha, not a bad idea. (Jokes)

However guys I found exactly what I'm looking for due to the help here. (this is one of the nicer exchanges I've ever posted too btw).

It's called a switched capacitor array, and it's a pretty exotic component that's used in scientific sampling of analog signals. The other option is an FPAA setup to do the same thing apparently... though it looks like those are in the 'R&D' stage for both.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched_capacitor

Thanks guys, you really helped me out.

Comment: Some of the early machines used a 'delay line memory' using acoustic delay lines, such things as trough lines filled with mercury were used (Dense, so high speed of sound), but if you can still find some you might be able to do something cool with a set of old TV croma delay lines (64us IIRC at @4.4MHz)?

Answer (score 1):

I might have read this wrong, however, you are not going to get the functionality you desire in an array. Nobody makes an IC that stores an analog value in an array, if there is anything its custom.

You can use IC's such as the [LT1043](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC1043) that have fast switching capabilities to 'store' voltage values in a capacitor. There are 4 switches per chip. Shown below is an example of how you would wire it to an instrumentation amplifier to provide chopping action to modulate DC for lower noise, but you can wire it to anything you like.

[image]

Comment: Bugger, this is close to what I'm looking for but still off.

Comment: Like I said, if your looking for addressing, your not going to find it in an IC, you'll have to 'roll your own'. IC's are produced when there is sufficient commercial demand for such a circuit.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing *almost* sounds like a [bucket-brigade device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket-brigade_device). These devices acted almost like a shift register for analog values, and were sometimes used to implement audio reverb or echo effects. However, they're essentially unavailable today, having been entirely replaced by digital effects.

Comment: Transferring an analog signal from one circuit to another 512 times sounds like it would be massively harder, and introduce massively more noise, than having 512 capacitors along with 512 switches to connect one cap to the output of one voltage follower and 512 to connect the next cap to the input of another voltage follower.  Would a 512-sample BBD internally copy each sample through 512 caps, or was that just a behavioral description?

Comment: @supercat Yes -- it's every bit as lossy a process as you might expect. There's a reason nobody makes them anymore. :)

Comment: Why not use an array of 512 caps, 512 input switches, and 512 output switches, along with a couple voltage followers?  I would think that would be cheaper and offer better performance.

Comment: @supercat That would have been a lot harder to fabricate. Keep in mind that these parts were manufactured as early as 1975 -- adding gates to make the array addressable would have forced the manufacturer to reduce the capacity of the array.

Comment: The bucket brigade idea is still in use on non-cmos based digital cameras. These CCD cameras appear at the high end now.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge-coupled_device

Comment: @duskwuff: One wouldn't need to add address decoding logic; simply put dynamic digital shift register next to the storage capacitors and cycle a "1" through the shift register to select which capacitor should be connected to the input bus or output bus.  Unless there's some magic I don't know of to make the sample/hold amplifiers used by a BBD wonderfully compact, I would think that having two ampilfiers, a shift register, and two sets of switches, would be more compact than having 2N amplifiers.